# Talend how to open talend.project file

Tags: talend

I am complete new to talend and inherited some projects from someone who has left our company. I can not figure out how to open the job and edit it.
I downloaded and is running Talend DI.
When I try to import the project I get the message.
"Selected folder is not a Talend Open Studio project."

The project files have look like this. (- represents a folder)

-ProjectName

-lib

jobinfo.properties

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That might not be a complete project folder , but rather the result of someone selecting one or more jobs (in a project) and exporting them.

Try this

- create a new project
- open it
- right click on jobs
- import
- navigate to the folder you mention as the source folder
- see if it finds any items (jobs, contexts, meta data definitions etc) to import
- for the sake of simplicity, import all available items into your newly created project
- review the jobs and other imported items

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, as a best practice,  I recommend checking the whole project into revision control. That makes it much easier for the next person ( or you) grab the latest project/code version and open it up, without having to figure out what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I managed to import the project into the workspace from Talend studio as below.

```
Open Talend Studio -> Import an Existing Project ->Select -> Import Several projects -> Select Root Directory (Browse the Folder) -> you would be able to see the available projects (if the project folder is not corrupted)->Select the project checkbox -> Click on Finish
```

Comment: Can we open .project files like this?

Comment: I think it will identify the .project file once you browse to the location.